# VirtualEnv in different operating systems

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv

I'm currently working on a school project in data analytics. We use OS X, Ubuntu and Windows, so we would like to know how to use the same code in all platforms. We created an virtual environment and installed all the external libraries needed, and when we change the folder to another operating system we run:

```
virtualenv path/to/virtualenvFolder --alwayscopy --download
```

But most of the libraries do not work, or have errors like *"permission denied..."*, even with sudo. Is there any good way of passing Python code and external libraries in a folder for several operating systems?

Comment: Virtualenvs **aren't designed to be portable**. You need to create a new virtual environment on the new machine and install the requirements in it (e.g. `pip freeze >> requirements.txt` on the old machine then `pip install -r requirements.txt` on the new one).

Answer (score 2):

You haven't really given much information here. But it sounds like you are including your virtualenv and its installed libraries in the code you share between systems. You shouldn't do that.

Only share the project code; each user should install their own copies of the dependencies directly. You should include a requirements.txt in the project which lists all these, and each developer can run `pip install -r requirements.txt` inside their own virtualenv.

Comment: Thank you. I thought we could install all the external libraries in the folder so we do not have to install every external library in every computer.