# ksh : ./bin/python2.7: cannot execute

Tags: python, virtualenv, aix

Hi all I am working with IBM AIX remote server and cannot get the python inside the virtualenv to execute, though I have activated the virtualenv. I created the virtualenv on my mac machine with the all the dependencies installed required to run the project as I don't have the admin privileges on the AIX box and need to deploy and run my app on the server.

I was able to activate the virtual environment on the aix box by running the below command

```
. ./project_name/bin/activate
```

I tried running the file using the path to the python inside the virtualenv

```
/u/.../project_name/bin/python2.7 myfile.py
```

but go the error

```
ksh: ./bin/python2.7: cannot execute
```

Whenever i try to check the python that is currently being executed I get the system python path as a result

```
which python
/bin/python
```

I want it to execute the python inside the virtualenv and use the libraries that I have installed in there for the app I want to run. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How was the virtualenv *created*? Was it created on this same machine, or somewhere else with a different OS/architecture?

Comment: If it was created on the local machine -- if you create a whole new virtualenv, activate it, and then try to invoke its Python interpreter, does that exhibit the same problem? If not, you'll need to build a [mcve] that describes the shortest necessary set of steps to let someone create the issue starting from scratch.

Comment: virtualenv was created on my mac machine and was deployed on a remote server.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [How can I make a Python virtualenv meant for another platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554093/how-can-i-make-a-python-virtualenv-meant-for-another-platform), or [VirtualEnv in different operating systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40449050/virtualenv-in-different-operating-systems) (note that the answer is roughly "you can't"; AIX can't run MacOS executables any more than a Mac ran run AIX executables).

Comment: ...that said, you can probably install the dependencies under the same home directory where you're placing the virtualenv, avoiding any need for admin privileges -- maybe get someone more comfortable with UNIX over to help you? Even if those dependencies are distributed only in packaged form, packages can be *unpacked* into locations other than the system root.